# How to make Vim package [matchit] work on a mixed html & js file?

Tags: javascript, html, vim, vim-plugin

Vim has a package called Matchit, which helps you jump from tag to tag using '%' key. This is quite helpful in html files, since you can jump from the starting  to ending , as well as starting '<' to ending '>'.
It seems that the way tag jumping works is that it changes from language to language. The above behaviour is stopped in a javascript file, and the jumping occurs on (), {} tags and so on.

I have the following problem:

I have a .tpl file, which contains both html and javascript, but % tag jumping for html elements doesn't work anymore. How can I enable mixed behaviour - html style jumping & js style jumping? Thanks.

Comment: How about `:set ftplugin=javascript.html` or `:set ftplugin=html.javascript`?

Comment: Heh, seems like I can just use :set filetype=html in .tpl files and it also works to jump in js functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` jumping to `()`, `{}`, `[]` is based on the built-in `'matchpairs'` option. The *matchit* plugin builds upon that and allows more complex jumps (like HTML tags).

As the HTML filetype just extends the `'matchpairs'` option, you can just use that filetype, also for mixed-mode files. (Many HTML files contain JavaScript snippets, anyway, so that's a well-supported combination.)

For me, `*.tpl` is by default detected as `filetype=smarty`. This filetype (in Vim 8.1) only supplies a syntax script, but no filetype settings.

You can inherit the HTML filetype settings (which include the matchit definitions) by creating `~/.vim/ftplugin/smarty.vim`:

```
if exists('b:did_ftplugin') | finish | endif
runtime! ftplugin/html.vim
runtime! ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```